# Django many to many field returns empty query set even after it has the the elements

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

this is my models.py and I add values in my admin panel and its showing values in admin panel but if I print the size_variant object it returns query set '[]'.

```
class ColorVariant(BaseModel):
    color_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.color_name

class SizeVariant(BaseModel):
    size_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.size_name



    


class Product(BaseModel):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,null=True,blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="products")
    original_price = models.IntegerField()
    discounted_price = models.IntegerField()
    product_description = models.TextField()
    color_variant = models.ManyToManyField(ColorVariant,blank=True)
    size_variant = models.ManyToManyField(SizeVariant,blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug= slugify(self.product_name)
        super(Product,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
# return self.product_name
```

this is my views.py

```
def get_product(request,slug):
    product_obj = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
   
    print(product_obj.size_variant.all())
    


  
    product_images = ProductImage.objects.filter(product__slug=slug)

    return render(request,'products/product.html',{'product_images':product_images,'product_obj':product_obj})
```

after running this its shows "<QuerySet []>"  how can I do it ??

Comment: So how do you know it has `size_variants`? Can you show the admin panel? Are you sure the slug matches?